# Creating loop to delete diagonal entries of a data set in SAS (replace them by ".")

Tags: sas

I have been trying to create a loop of sorts that would delete diagonals of my data set. My code, however, ends up deleting all columns. I think the issue is that I do not know how to reference a specific entry in a column (I would like to implement something like: if i = j then replace row = j with ".", where i and j are the looping indices). For example in R you can select an entry as columnName[1], but I am not sure how this works in SAS. I know *N* is related somehow but my code ends up deleting the entire column (replacing it by ".").

Any suggestions on how I could fix this? Many thanks.

Code used:

```
data want ;
set have;
array column column_1 -- column_100; 
do over column; 
do _N_ = 1 to 100;
column = ".";
end;
end;
run;
```

(So for the 6th row, for column, I want to somehow reference a specific row. Also I have 100 columns in total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`_N_`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p1kfea7go1hi5qn1beilekqz6pf2.htm) automatic variable created automatically by the DATA step or by DATA step statements alongside with an array.
`_N_` is initially set to 1. Each time the DATA step loops past the DATA statement, the variable increments by 1. The value of `_N_` represents the number of times the DATA step has iterated.

Example shown below.

```
data have;
input column1 column2 column3 column4;
cards;
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
;

data want;
set have;
array col column:;
do i=1 to dim(col);
    if _n_ = i then col[i] = 0;
end;

drop i;
run;
```

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       0 |       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
|       1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Many thanks! Also may I ask what the : in column: does?

Comment: The colon operator (:) is used to specify a list of variables that begin with a common prefix. There are many ways you can [specify a list of variables in SAS](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html). Please consider accepting the answer if you think this helped.